# VBA : Copying non-contiguous data from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a Worksheet where I have to filter out certain data, based on a particular date. After writing the code to filter the data using `Range.AutoFilter`, I wish to copy the visible data in the worksheet (which is non-contiguous) to another worksheet. For this I am using

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ImportDumpData")
    .Activate
    'frow variable counts the total number of rows in the sheet
    frow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Columns("U:U").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    .Range("U2:U" & frow).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("C4"), Operator:=xlEnd
    .Range("A1:AF" & frow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
End With
```

The error message pops up saying "Microsoft Office Excel cannot create or use the data range reference because it is too complex" for this `.Range("A1:AF" & row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` line of code.
Please Suggest what can be done.

Comment: what is value of `row` variable? And i suggest you to try use `.range(sheet.cells(1,"A"),sheet.cells(row,"AF")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` and dont forget to declare sheet variable with sheet where you wana to perform operation. Or i just noticed that you using `with` statement, so you can omit `sheet`in my example and just use `.cells`

Comment: I've Edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: And I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$518").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">"
  .Range("A:AF" & frow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

use and this for your code

Comment: could you please disclose exact requirement here.